# Can't use 100% of my hard drive partition

Tags: partitioning, permissions, hard-drive, ext4

I'm a newbie in Ubuntu. I recently received my laptop with Linux Mint and Ubuntu 14.04. I didn't know how to format this, so I just used it the way I know. Then whenever I tried to write something in the "217 GB VOLUME" it says `error while copying, permission denied`.

So up until now, I'm just using 28GB of storage and I need to use some more storage, but I don't really understand what partitioning is.

Plus the computer name is still the past owner of this laptop. Does it has a connection with using 100% of my hard drive disk space?

```
boi@stanislav-VGN-CS110E:~$ grep sudo /etc/group
sudo:x:27:boi
boi@stanislav-VGN-CS110E:~$ lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL MOUNTPOINT
sda                 
├─sda1              /
├─sda2              
├─sda5              [SWAP]
└─sda6              /media/boi/92e9f385-9a3d-45b1-afca-a2a3aab1c8e4
sr0                 
boi@stanislav-VGN-CS110E:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        28G   18G  8.9G  67% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.4G   12K  1.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs           288M  2.3M  286M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.5G  245M  1.2G  17% /run/shm
none            100M   60K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda6       199G  3.9G  185G   3% /media/boi/92e9f385-9a3d-45b1-afca-a2a3aab1c8e4

boi@stanislav-VGN-CS110E:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>     boi@stanislav-VGN-CS110E:~$ cat /etc/fstab
<options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=e6ad514d-9067-4f17-b054-55bd77ee5657 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=ffc2b211-4ac1-48c1-be7b-d2c80c182cb4 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

mount command's output

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpu)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,relatime,hugetlb)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1001/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=boi)
/dev/sda6 on /media/boi/92e9f385-9a3d-45b1-afca-a2a3aab1c8e4 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Comment: Open a terminal and run `lsblk -f` and `df -h` and add it to your post!

Comment: Also, from a terminal (start one with Ctrl + Alt + T ) check that your username is in the sudo group with the command:  
    grep sudo /etc/group

Comment: i did added it but i don't know how to add it as code. i just copy paste it. sorry

Comment: cat you also edit your question to include the content of `/etc/fstab`

Comment: also, your hostname shouldn't matter. Its set in `/etc/hostname`. If you change this, you should also change it in `/etc/hosts` (its probably on the line starting 127.0.1.1)

Comment: when ever i use `/etc/fstab/` i'm always getting this `boi@stanislav-VGN-CS110E:~$ /etc/fstab

bash: /etc/fstab: Permission denied`

Comment: `/etc/fstab` is a text file, not a command. To print its contents, use `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: i changed it now. hope i got it right this time.

Comment: i'm not using the `/dev/sda6` for anything. i don't really know how.

Comment: Maybe the inode count of your ext4 filesystem is to large that "consumes" the space..

Comment: i don't really know

Comment: Thank you for including the `mount` output but it’s missing the line I’ve been interested in… Please repeat the command with the `/dev/sda6` partition (probably the "217 GB VOLUME") mounted, like you had when you posted your `lsblk` and `df -h` output. (You can also use `mount | grep sda6` to print just the single line, the output must be not empty.) Please [ping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/217657) me after you post the requested information.

Comment: @Melebius `/dev/sda6 on /media/boi/92e9f385-9a3d-45b1-afca-a2a3aab1c8e4 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)` is this it? thanks btw.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I wanted. Now I know the partition is mounted as read-write (`rw`) and has the type `ext4` which maintains file permissions. So could you please add the output of `ls -l /media/boi/92e9f385-9a3d-45b1-afca-a2a3aab1c8e4`? Most likely the owner and group (3rd and 4th column) won’t be you (`boi`). In this case, `sudo chown -R boi:boi /media/boi/92e9f385-9a3d-45b1-afca-a2a3aab1c8e4` would be the solution.

Comment: @Melebius it did work now. i can write files in it now. thank you so much. i appreciate your kindness. :) i tried the`ls -l /media/boi/92e9f385-9a3d-45b1-afca-a2a3aab1c8e4` and i'm the owner now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `mount` output:

```
/dev/sda6 on /media/boi/92e9f385-9a3d-45b1-afca-a2a3aab1c8e4 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
```

the partition in question is mounted as read-write (`rw`) which is correct and the type is `ext4` which is default on Ubuntu. This filesystem maintains file permissions (unlike FAT or NTFS, for example).
Since this partition does not appear in your `/etc/fstab` file, it was probably created by another Linux installation, in your case Mint.

The file permissions are still kept, including the original owner of the files which is most likely different from your current user ID. To reset owner of all files on the partition to you (`boi`), run the following command:

```
sudo chown -R boi:boi /media/boi/92e9f385-9a3d-45b1-afca-a2a3aab1c8e4
```

Then you should be able to write into this partition.

If you’re going to use the partition regularly, you should create a permanent mount point for it and add it to `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: how should i create a permanent mount point?

Comment: @Ashrd A [mount point](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/mount-point) is just a regular folder which you provide as an argument to the `mount` command or put into the `/etc/fstab` file. The mounted partition then provides the contents (files, subfolders) of the folder. If I should reply more specifically, you must tell what data would you store there, resp. where the mounted partition should be available in the [directory structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).